# SUBSTITUTE function on dynamic array - new trick and strange behavior

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

SUBSTITUTE(text, old_text, new_text, [instance_num])

Three required arguments.

Today my puzzle was to generate a dynamic array with a constant text value, i.e. "Huey" * however many rows.  Part of the ultimate solution of displaying the column header when any value in columns B through whatever matches the value in column A same row.

Please tell me I am not going crazy:

[image: screenshot formula and table]

SEQUENCE generates numbers.  Passed to SUBSTITUTE's second argument are

1. A numeric text string not present in any SEQUENCE as text or number
2. A text string that is impossible to generate in SEQUENCE
3. Nothing.  This is not supposed to be possible, it is a required argument.

Can somebody please explain this?  Do I have to point this out to Microsoft?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what issue you are referring to. Although may not be the issue you want to discuss with MS, you might be able to clean up your formula by using `BYROW()` and (`FILTER()` OR `XLOOKUP()`

Comment: TY gns I just figured it out with BYROW and it's so simple I want to slap my forehead.  Still want to know why that formula executes with a missing required parameter and in other strange ways.